# jQuery using untilNext() > descendants

Tags: jquery

I need to get all the .section elements between child elements h2.
My code toggles all elements; untilNext(a b) is not selecting up to element with descendant b.  Do I need another approach or is something wrong that I am not seeing?

html:
'

```
<div class='section' id='section-4'>
<div class='docs'>
  <div class='octowrap'>
    <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-4'>#</a>
  </div>
  <h2>todo     <br></h2>
   <p>main.html   <br></p>
</div>
<div class='code'>
  <div class="highlight"><pre><span class="n">colorific</span></pre></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='clearall'></div>
<div class='section' id='section-5'>
<div class='docs'>
  <div class='octowrap'>
    <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-5'>#</a>
  </div>
  <p>containers  <br></p>
</div>
<div class='code'>

</div>
<div class='clearall'></div>
<div class='section' id='section-6'>
 <div class='docs'>
  <div class='octowrap'>
    <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-6'>#</a>
  </div>
  <h2>nextH2</h2>
 </div>
 <div class='code'>
  <div class="highlight"><pre><span class="n">blah</span></pre></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='clearall'></div>
```

translates to:

```
great-grandparent <div class='section' id='section-18'>
   grandparent       <div class='docs'>
    parent        <div class='octowrap'>
        *          <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-18'>#</a>
        h2        <h2> </h2>
```

js:

```
$(function(){                                                                                                                      |   
$('.octothorpe').on({                                                                                                          |-  vimwiki_docs.py (/home/solver/webpag1)
    click:function(e){                                                                                                         |   
        e.preventDefault();                                                                                                    |-  vimwiki_docs.html (/home/solver/webpag1/docs)
        var $pfold = $(this).closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');                                                               |   
        var $cfold = $(this).closest('.docs').siblings('.code');                                                               |-  knowl.js (/home/solver/webpag1/docs)
        var $sector = $(this).closest('.section');                                                                             ||-   global
        var $h2 = $sector.nextUntil('.section > h2');                                                                          |||     knowl_id_counter
        //var $h2 = $sector.nextAll('div').each(function(){                                                                    ||  
        //  //this within iteration refers to h2 div element                                                                   ||-   function
        //  if ($(this).is('h2')) {                                                                                            |||     knowl_click_handler
        //      return false;                                                                                                  |   
        //  }})                                                                                                                |   ~                                              
                                                                                                                               |   ~                                              
        //});//close each()                                                                                                    |   ~                                              
        $pfold.toggleClass('fold');                                                                                            |   ~                                              
        $cfold.toggleClass('fold');                                                                                            |   ~                                              
        $h2.toggleClass('fold');                                                                                               |   ~                                              
            //console.log('h2', $h2)                                                                                           |   ~                                              
            //if (!$h2.hasClass("fold") && !$pfold.hasClass("fold") && !$cfold.hasClass("fold")) {                             |   ~                                              
            //  $cfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');                                                                             |   ~                                              
            //  $pfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');                                                                             |   ~                                              
            //  $h2.slideUp().addClass('fold');                                                                                |   ~                                              
            //}                                                                                                                |   ~                                              
            //else {                                                                                                           |   ~                                              
            //  $cfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');                                                                        |   ~                                              
            //  $pfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');                                                                        |   ~                                              
            //  $h2.slideDown().removeClass('fold');                                                                           |   ~                                              
            //}                                                                                                                |   ~                                              
                                                                                                                               |   ~                                              
    }});                                                                                                                       |   ~
```

});

I tried nextUntil and nextAll with each and return false... no luck!

any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Your selector `var $h2 = $sector.nextUntil('.section > h2');` is wrong, it should be `var $h2 = $sector.find('h2');`

Comment: Also the requirement is not clear,

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, and will answer in case someone else new to the jQuery api runs into the same problem:
`

```
 var $sector = $(this).nextUntil('section:has(h2)').slice(0,-1);
```

`

1. So I have a h2 in a child position.  Using closest I can go up to the grandparent div.section:
2. Now I want to search to the next h2, also a child.  In the case where I want all elements up the first match, use nextUntil().  {find as suggested in comments grabs all the items you are searching for, not the set needed}

   nextUntil() only selects siblings.  Therefore, use has() to select on children/descendants.
3. i needed to slice the last element.  I played with section:not(:last) without much luck, so discovering slice in jQuery made things easy.